# Cocoa read string character by character?

Tags: string, cocoa

I am aiming to create an app which receives an NSString, like "A12EE345", then reads the string character by character, perhaps in a for loop, and performs an action on each character. A bit like reading a file line by line, but reading a string character by character?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should read apple documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *inputString = @"A12EE345";
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++) {
    NSString *character = [inputString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    NSLog(@"Character: %@", character);
}
```

Comment: Or use `characterAtIndex:`, the `unichar` type, and the `%C` formatting sequence.